# Matlab data structure

Tags: matlab

I am doing gene expression data analysis using a pipeline. the data is .mat. but it is invisible.

[image]

but my data is as below

[image]

I want to format my data like the first picture. But I do not know how.

For prostates2 code like:

load data/cancer/prostate2/prostate2

```
tsn_data = PrepTSNLabels(prostate2.Data, prostate2.Calls,   prostate2.classes, 1);

[tsn_cv] = CrossValidateTSN(tsn_data, leaveout, iterations, rangeN,           rangeDEG, mas5Cutoff, icv, use_gpu, debug);

**PrepTSNLabels:**

[tsn_data] = PrepTSN(data, calls, class1, class2, debug)

if (nargin < 5)
debug = 0;

class1 = class1(:);
class2 = class2(:);

tempdata = data(:, [class1; class2]);

tempcalls = [];
if (~isempty(calls))
tempcalls = calls(:, [class1; class2]);

labels = single(zeros(1, size(tempdata, 2)));
labels(ismember(colnames(tempdata), class2)) = 1;       

tsn_data = struct;
tsn_data.data = tempdata;
tsn_data.calls = tempcalls;
tsn_data.labels = labels;
```

I do not know how to change my data to use the command above?

Comment: It's impossible to say what any of those variables are without seeing your code. Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask[, then [edit] your question accordingly. You'll most likely need a [mcve], a piece of code reproducing the problem you are facing. Please provide sample input and output, as well as errors, if you get any.

Comment: Please put your updates in the question itself by clicking on the [edit] link, not in the answer box below.